# C# Selenium copy text

Tags: c#, selenium

```
<td style="padding:10px;color:#565a5c;font-size:32px;font-weight:500;text-align:center;padding-bottom:25px;">836712</td>
```

I want to copy the number "836712" above but have no idea how to do it. Please help me.
The above codes are taken from a site.
I want to copy using C# selenium.

plss

Answer (score 0):

use the getText() function on the WebElement.
Since you only pasted the td element i can't know the hierarchy of the html.
Focus on a parent with an ID (that renders it unique) then using JS cycle trough its children for **n** times where **n** is the number of the td element you're searching for from parent.
Then use getText() on it.

[take a look here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-the-child-element-of-a-parent-using-javascript/)

Code snippet (to convert from Java):

```
        String code = "";

        yourWebElementsArray = driver.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    
        for(WebElement el: yourWebelementsArray) {
    
    if(el.getAttribute("color").equals("#565a5c") && el.getAttribute("font-size").equals("32px")) {

  code = el.getText();

}

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately i've never written code in C#, i can write for you a snippet in java that you could convert. But you should give me the URL of the page you're trying to automate.

Comment: I can't find the WE you're asking for even if i tried to send myself an email, please post a pic of the page with the td visible, ty.

Comment: Do you only need to take the code from an instagram email? Or must it be a general code for another site asking you a code?

Comment: only instagram site